# SQL Group BY / JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

[SQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Gtv.png)

Hi, please check attached picture, I have the data on the sql grid and I want to get the preferred output. any help will be very much appreciated. thank you very much.

Comment: Please state your problem instead of posting a picture

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i'm using MS SQL 2015

Comment: Hi @Anuraag, 

as you can see on the attached photo.

my data is as follows:


Company_Code  Status
1  FOR APPROVAL
1  FOR AUTHORIZATION
2  FOR AUTHORIZATION
3  FOR APPROVAL

what I want to get as output is:
COMPANY_CODE FOR_APPROVAL FOR_AUTHORIZATION
1  1  1
2  0  1
3  1  0

Thanks

Comment: Not as a comment, edit your question instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with the help of `case` expression

```
SELECT company_code,
       sum(case when Status = 'FOR APPROVAL' then 1 else 0 end) FOR_APPROVAL,
       sum(case when Status = 'FOR AUTHORIZATION' then 1 else 0 end) FOR_AUTHORIZATION
FROM table
GROUP BY company_code
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: SELECT company_code,
       sum(case when status = 'FOR APPROVAL' then 1 else 0 end) FOR_APPROVAL,
       sum(case when status = 'FOR AUTHORIZATION' then 1 else 0 end) FOR_AUTHORIZATION
FROM tbl_CheckMaster
GROUP BY company_code

Answer (score 0):

@Yogesh Sharma is right, You can just use the Sum with the Case expression.

```
SELECT company_code,
       sum(case when st = 'FOR APPROVAL' then 1 else 0 end) FOR_APPROVAL,
       sum(case when st = 'FOR AUTHORIZATION' then 1 else 0 end) FOR_AUTHORIZATION
FROM table
GROUP BY company_code
```

More informations you can get [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)